# Understanding Javascript Functions and Closure

Tags: javascript

In the following example, how is y given the value of 1?  I added some logging to see values and don't understand how/where y is assigned...

```
(function() {
    function foo(x) {
        var callNum = 0;
        var baz = 3;
        return function (y) {
            callNum++;
            console.log("callNum: " + callNum);
            console.log("y: " + y);
            console.log("baz: " + baz);
            console.log("x: " + x);
            console.log(x + y + (++baz));
        }
    }
var moo = foo(2); // moo is now a closure.
moo(1);
moo(1);
})();
```

Here's the fiddle output log:

```
    callNum: 1   
    y: 1   
    baz: 3
    x: 2 
    7 
    callNum: 2 
    y: 1 
    baz: 4 
    x: 2 
    8
```

Comment: The question should be: "What's inside `moo`?". Once you got that, it's pretty clear where the `y` get's assigned ;)

Comment: Why would you expect `y` to not be 1?

Comment: `y` isn't "assigned" it is passed into the function `moo` which is the function returned by `foo`.  Both times, you pass a `1`, so it's 1.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is new concept and your answers really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

`foo()` returns a function.  This returned function accepts a single argument, the `y` you are concerned with.

So when you do this:

```
// returns a function that accepts `y` with `x` shared via closure
var moo = foo(2);

// execute the inner function, passing in a value for `y`.
moo(1);
```

`foo(2)` returns a function.  `x` is now `2`.  `moo` is now a function that accepts a value for `y`, and you pass in `1`.  So `y` is now `1`.

---

To think of it another way, you can invoke your inner function by doing:

```
foo(x)(y);
```

Or with the values you are using:

```
foo(2)(1);
```

So, in answer to your question, `y` gets set to `1` when you do:

```
moo(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
(function() {
    function foo(x) {
        var callNum = 0;
        var baz = 3;
```

These are the parameters that matter (*x*, *callNum* and *baz*). They form closures involving the following function:

```
        return function (y) {
```

This function has a closure to each of the outer local variables (including *moo* and *foo*).

```
            callNum++;
            console.log("callNum: " + callNum);
            console.log("y: " + y);
            console.log("baz: " + baz);
            console.log("x: " + x);
            console.log(x + y + (++baz));
        }
    }
```

There are also closures involving `moo` and both the above functions, however it's not used so is irrelevant to the outcome.

```
var moo = foo(2); // moo is now a closure.
```

The rest is answered by Alex.